# Euler Project: Largest palindrome product

Tags: python, palindrome

a python beginner here.
I am trying to do Project Euler Largest palindrome product and did following:

```
a = range(100, 999)
z = []
for x in a:
    for y in a:
        c = str(x*y)
    if c[0] == c[-1] and c[1] == c[-2] and c[2] == c[-3]:
        z.append(c)
print(z)
```

And I don't get what I expected. Not the most sophisticated solution but thought it would give the answer. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: The challenge asks to return one number. You print a list...

Comment: Yes you are right but the list itself doesn't even contain a palindrome

Comment: Is the `if` indented the correct way? It seems weird to just override the c in the inner loop and then continue only with the last value.

Comment: @MangoNrFive Yes that was the issue. Thank you so much!